What if a potential employer knows that you are working on a stealth startup on the side?
I am a software developer.
On my linkedin page, I have my most recent experience as being the founder of a "Stealth" startup.
On my resume, I briefly describe a "passion project" that I've been working on for a couple of years.
Questions:

How do recruiters view this?
How do potential employers view this? Would they mark you down as a potential flight risk, and hence less likely to extend an offer?


Are you going to be pursuing funding while employed by someone? Will this startup be in competition with a company you work with? What are the timelines for funding, growth, expansion? As someone who hires people, if you're a couple of years in and haven't found the funding or room to go full time on it, it's not going anywhere. This wouldn't even be a footnote for me in an interview.

As an employer, what I've done in this situation multiple times is (from the employer's view):
ASK QUESTIONS
Make it a talking point during the interview process.
Be clear that I am not asking about the specifics, but what they are hoping to accomplish. Do they want to be a business person. How far are they in their process.
Hiring someome that has ideas points towards talent/productivity. It doesn't guarantee it, but is better than hiring someone that shows no interest in other than a pay check.
People that are constantly thinking and either want to be in business or poached by other companies tend to be the most talented. IT IS THE EMPLOYERS JOB TO RETAIN THEM! Not be afraid of them - within reason.
That said, I've talked to a lot of fools that have no clue about what it takes to start a business. If they are so full of themselves, they won't be good employees either.
It is possible to get two or three years of good value and mentoring a new friend by hiring someone that does want to do a start up.
Face it - Most, darn near all start ups fail. I have learned to be more concerned with hubris than flight risk.
I don't really see it as much of a difference between one of my team members that works on open source on their own time and their other side projects. I would rather it be out in the open.
Flight risk? Nah - not really any more than anyone else.
Underperformer? Nah - Managers are supposed to manage. Any employee that is an habitual unperformer needs to be addressed regardless of possible reason.
Just be honest (minimal info is OK) that you have outside interests that are similar to the job you are applying for.

I think a reasonable subset of employers will be like @DogBoy37, love that you have the passion to make stuff and will be please to have a year or two of you on your way to that startup.
Another subset will absolutely hate it.
You probably want to work for the first.

It took me a long time to understand that if I wanted talented team members that I needed to encourage them. Until I learned it, I chased off a lot of good people.

It's probably also a question of how you talk about your "stealth startup". Frankly I wouldn't even call it a "stealth startup", it's a side project that may or may not eventually mature into a startup. This is not a time when you want to upsell the seriousness of your side gig.

Until you make money from it or get funding, it is a hobby. When you can live off of it, then it is a business. If you own a tech business whether you want to or not, you are an incubator. There is nothing wrong with employing hard working / thinking people that have their own visions. They will remember who helped them on the way up.

You are a potential flight risk, but more importantly, there is a good chance that you wouldn't work 40 hours a week as expected. Or you might try, but would not start in a refreshed state but end up exhausted.

Why is exhaustion more of a risk for someone who programs in their spare time, vs. someone who raises children?

@kaya3, In the US, asking if you have children during an interview is illegal precisely for that reason. An employer may decide not to hire you because of that. On the other hand, there is no such legal protection for someone doing a stealth startup on the side.

@StephanBranczyk It is not just illegal to select against employees who have children, but also many employers wouldn't dream of doing it, because they find it totally acceptable for their employees to raise children in their personal time anyway. If those employers are consistent, they should likewise not select against employees who write code in their personal time.

@kaya3, This is assuming the stealth startup job was/is even real. For all a potential employer knows, the stealth startup is just a shell company with an attractive web site designed to fill in the gaps of resumes of a group of friends.

@kaya3 - I can see why it might be different - going home every evening and spending time with one's children - while it can be tiring - can be a welcome break from programming all day. However, spending all day programming, then going home and doing more programming for the rest of the evening greatly increases the risk of burnout. "A change is as good as a rest" and all that.

@komodosp – As a father of two, programming is sometimes a welcome break from spending time with the kids all day :-)

@kaya3 nonsense. And there are other reasons, pressing reasons. The employee might try to steal your customers away from them or worse, run off with your know how and use that to compete against you. I've worked for several companies that had employees try to do just that. They got caught, fired on the spot, and sued into the ground.

@jwenting That has nothing to do with this answer, which is about the employee's capability to work vs. not being refreshed, being exhausted.


Would they mark you down as a potential flight risk, and hence less
likely to extend an offer?

I know many employers who would think exactly this.

This definitely is a tricky situation. While a lot of employers will see you as a risky hire for the flight risks as you mentioned, and if I ignore all other aspects like your project isn't their direct competition & that you would manage time and availability etc., those who would still hire you, I bet they would speculate your side ventures be the cause for any delays that happened with your task's completion.

From my perspective as a past employer, its a red flag. Even if you had your own business in the past, you are still a flight risk.  Once a business person, always a business person.
But having a current side business is a no no. Also, many employers' contracts will have clauses where they own everything you create while in their employment,  even if it is outside work hours and off premises.

is there a name for the kind of clause that you mentioned where they own everything you create?

In many jurisdictions an employment agreement like that is unenforceable. Two I know of are California and the UK.

When there is such a clause, it can often be negotiated to carve out specific exceptions, as long as there is not a strong overlap between the two businesses. For example, when I was hired I had a clause written into the contract explicitly excluding work on a patent in an unrelated field that I was participating in. Also, a well-written version of that clause will explicitly say that it only addresses conflicts in the companies areas of interest, though admittedly it may be necessary to explicitly nail down whether a specific effort is or is not within that scope.

@BearBileFarmingisTorture It's just a very expansive IP clause.  As others have noted they're not applicable in all jurisdictions, where they are legal, they're more common in larger businesses and those that create their own IP.  Smaller and less innovative ones will mostly just want to know about your side projects so they can avoid conflict of interest hazards.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight what do you mean by expensive?

@BearBileFarmingisTorture not expEnsive, expAnsive:  Meaning it's scope has been expanded to a very large extent.

In some jurisdictions (such as Germany) that is even the default e.g. for code. Thus, side business in stealth mode would possibly be doomed due to you not owning the IP you want to sell. The only way to do this is to be open about the business and negotiate appropriate IP clauses.

same in the Netherlands. Pretty much every contract prohibits ANY work on the side, often including open source projects, and claims ANYTHING created inside and outside of work hours (whether relevant to the company business or not. So technically that chicken coop you built in the garden over the weekend could be claimed by your employer as theirs, not that that's likely to happen if you work in IT)

@jwenting AFAIK, that is against the law in NL. The employer may require that they're informed, but a default "no" is not allowed (the employer must demonstrate a "zwaarwegend belang" before they can forbid something), and they also cannot claim ownership of things created in your own time that are not directly related to the business of your employer.

@MarkRotteveel it's illegal in theory, in practice most individuals won't have the resources to fight it, especially if their (former) employer is a larger company (if they even know it's illegal).

If your startup is a direct competitor to your employer, that's (hopefully) obvious that it's a no-go and should be disclosed from the get go.
My main practical concern when hiring applicants is that of split attention. Even if you intend to only work on this after hours, what happens if you get a call during work hours?
And even if you explicitly state that you have concretely planned to only work out of office hours, there's still concerns that (a) you're not telling the truth, (b) you're being naive/idealistic about this and (c) you might end up working too many hours in a week which is going to negatively impact your per-hour productivity.
I wouldn't immediately dismiss such a candidate, but I would very much observe their character and how they talk about the startup, and how much I trust their judgment of how they intend to manage their time and effort.

Would they mark you down as a potential flight risk, and hence less likely to extend an offer?

In the current IT market, especially software development, everyone is a flight risk. I can't speak for every company obviously, but most companies today are aware that software engineers tend to job-hop instead of sticking with a single company for career growth, so I wouldn't be too concerned about you as a flight risk.
However, some companies still want their staff to be in it for the long run and might judge this differently. In my personal opinion and observation, it's highly likely that such a company doesn't have a contemporary understanding of the software development ecosystem and that would generally turn me away from wanting to work for them in the first place for ulterior reasons.


How do recruiters view this?

Each recruiter would have their own opinion. It is impossible that ALL recruiters think identically.

How do potential employers view this?

Same as with recruiters, employers have different opinions.

Would they mark you down as a potential flight risk, and hence less likely to extend an offer?

That is not really the important question. The important question is: Should you do your best to avoid a conflict of interests with your employer? And the answer is: "Definitely YES." - even if they did not notice your private stuff, or if they prefer to not talk about it. In a later (potential) legal battle, they will be a lot more powerful than you. Even if you will win, your life will not be enjoyable.
At the beginning of a previous job, the employer asked me specifically if I have any previous personal / private intellectual property, and in case of "yes", to fully document it, in order to detect and mitigate potential conflicts of interest.
And that is exactly what you should do. Be open about the situation, explain the situation. Work with the potential employer to find a mutually beneficial compromise. It might be impossible to reach an agreement with some employers, but you should have no significant problems with others.
You need to clarify at least: the kind of intellectual property (musical, mechanical, software...), the amount of time you currently spend on your startup, the estimated amount of work you will need to spend in the future for your private endeavor etc.
I do not advise you to tell the potential employer the secret details of your private endeavor. However, as I gave you the example earlier, you might need to document the exact borders of the claimed personal intellectual property - and maybe to actually achieve legal protection for it, if it is the case - in order to avoid future problems.
BONUS: If your personal intellectual property is valuable to the company, they might want to buy your startup, or at least the intellectual property - additionally to hiring you. Even more, you might get paid to continue working for your project after employment - just not as an owner.
